# Why is my "let = " value different from my snapshot value?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement an id/token for the fcm push notification. I stored the id/token in my firebase database. I am having an issue getting the constant value to match the snapshot value. Here is code and a picture.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

```
let database = self.ref.child("\(safetyEmail)").child("uid")
               
let otherUseruid = database.observe(.value) { snapshot in

    guard let ouid = snapshot.value as? String else {
        return
    }
    
    print("this is the ouid: \(ouid)")

}

print("this is the otherUseriD: \(otherUseruid)")
```

What isn't the otherUseruid the same value as the ouid?

Comment: The screenshot says that an error occurred, `success: 0, failure: 1`

Comment: yes, that is a separate issue it has to do with an Invalid Registration. I am trying to get a user's uid to be the registration/fcm token.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. If you check the order in which the code is executed, you'll see that this `print("this is the otherUseriD` runs before `print("this is the ouid:`. This is the expected behavior, and means that any code that needs the data from the database needs to be inside the callback/closure, be called from there, or needs to be synchronized with a dispatch group. I've linked a few previous questions that cover this, and you can fine more example here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bswift%5d%20asynchronous%20